# loading CSS from angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to developement in aangular js. I have a task of loading the CSS template for page dynamically, by taking the name of CSS template from JSON object returned from the http Servlet. I need to call angular before the page is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the way to solve my problem, the best way to approach this is to understand the bootstrapping of application. As far as calling the script before RENDERING the page is concerned, I followed the explanation and example discussed at: 
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap 
This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-href`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) directive like this:

```
<link ng-href="{{file}}" type="text/css"/>
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BxnytZrRh2zah9xn6MaA)

Comment: I have tried using it but the element {{file}} does not pick up the value of CSS template returned from the servlet. I need a way to call my angular script before the page is renedered to the user, because CSS needs to be set when user sees the page.